# Remove all a tags from string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby, string

I have a string that is being input by the user. They can add as many links as they link but we only want some users to be able to click a link. What I am trying to do is replace any a tag with just the text inside it. I have managed to do it if there is one link but can't figure out how to do it when there are multiple.

This is what I currently have and have tried many variations to get to this:

```
url_text = text.split("<a").last.split("</a>").first.split('>').last
text.gsub! /<a.+a>/m, url_text
```

But it only works for the first instance of a tag.

The string I am receiving looks like this:

```
text = <div>blah blah blah.<br /><br /></div>\r\n<div><a href=\"http://www.google.com\">Google</a><br />Another link: <br /> <a href=\"http://www.test.com\">Test Link</a><br /><br /></div>"
```

I want it to say: 
blah blah blah.
Google
Another Link:
Test Link

Any help will be appreciated. Let me know if you need more code or info.

Comment: Obligatory.... **[DO NOT PARSE HTML WITH REGEX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1954610)**. TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ

Your code probably won't work properly for all edge cases, and it's typically a *very bad idea* to let users input arbitrary HTML like this -- you leave yourself wide open to XSS attacks.

Comment: A much better idea would be to explicitly whitelist specific HTML tags (perhaps with different lists for different users), using an HTML parser. Not regex. https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-sanitize -- This method is probably all you need.

Comment: @TomLord - Good point which is why I was asking thinking there must be a better way. It is only super users that can enter it and it is coming from tinymce so they aren't adding the html themselves.

Comment: Using a WYSIWYG editor does not protect you against malicious users. You can still submit arbitrary data in the form. But if you fully trust the users, then (as with most things) security is less of a concern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`strip_tags`](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-strip_tags) (to strip all tags) or [`strip_links`](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-strip_links) (to strip just links).

In Rails console:

```
> text = '<div>blah blah blah.<br /><br /></div>\r\n<div><a href=\"http://www.google.com\">Google</a><br />Another link: <br /> <a href=\"http://www.test.com\">Test Link</a><br /><br /></div>'
=> "<div>blah blah blah.<br /><br /></div>\\r\\n<div><a href=\\\"http://www.google.com\\\">Google</a><br />Another link: <br /> <a href=\\\"http://www.test.com\\\">Test Link</a><br /><br /></div>"
> helper.strip_tags(text)
=> "blah blah blah.\\r\\nGoogleAnother link:  Test Link"
```

Comment: I went with strip_links since I want to keep the other tags in there. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use rails helper

```
ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer.sanitize('text = <div>blah blah blah.<br /><br /></div>\r\n<div><a href=\"http://www.google.com\">Google</a><br />Another link: <br /> <a href=\"http://www.test.com\">Test Link</a><br /><br /></div>"
')

"text = blah blah blah.\\r\\nGoogleAnother link:  Test Link\"\n"
```

Comment: Will this also remove ERB tags and anything in between them?

Answer (score 2):

@mrzasa seems to have cracked it, though if you're wondering why the regex didn't work, it's due to it being too greedy.

Using the `?` lazy operator means a scan returns as few characters of the criteria as possible.

The following adds lazy operators to the search, and I believe works as you intended:

```
text = "<div>blah blah blah.<br /><br /></div>\r\n<div><a href=\"http://www.google.com\">Google</a><br />Another link: <br /> <a href=\"http://www.test.com\">Test Link</a><br /><br /></div><div>blah blah blah.<br /><br /></div>\r\n<div><a href=\"http://www.google.com\">Google</a><br />Another link: <br /> <a href=\"http://www.test.com\">Test Link</a><br /><br /></div>"
text.gsub(/<a.*?>(.+?)<\/a>/, '\1')

# => "<div>blah blah blah.<br /><br /></div>\r\n<div>Google<br />Another link: <br /> Test Link<br /><br /></div><div>blah blah blah.<br /><br /></div>\r\n<div>Google<br />Another link: <br /> Test Link<br /><br /></div>"
```

`'\1'` as the second argument of `gsub` simply replaces with the first match.

Hope that's in some way useful, and gives a flexible option if you'd rather use regex.

Comment: it's better to use limited character set than lazy operators: `/<a[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/a>/`. I've described it in a [blogpost](https://medium.com/textmaster-engineering/performance-of-regular-expressions-81371f569698)

Comment: Ah, great, thanks @mrzasa, appreciate the feedback. Will read through your link, and implement myself in future.

Comment: Good, leave comments on medium if you have any questions, I'll be happy to answer!

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-strip_tags), `strip_tags` is a method of `ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper` module. For me worked just to include this module in my class and then you can use it's method like this:

```
strip_tags(your_text_with_html)
```